# Reading CSV into C Struct

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a CSV into a struct in C.  I need to read in an item name, its weight and its value.  They are listed straight through in the CSV i.g (name, name, name, ..., weight, weight, ..., value, value, ..).

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[25];
    double weight;
    double value;
} Item;

int main() {

    // Open data.csv
    FILE *packingList;
    packingList = fopen("data.csv", "r");

    // Check for proper file Opening
    if (packingList == NULL) {
        printf("File did not open correctly.\n");
        return 1; // Signal error
    }

    // Declare array of items to store data
    Item items[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        fscanf(packingList,
               "%24[^,]",
               items[i].name);
        printf("| %s | ", items[i].name);
    }

    fclose(packingList);


    return 0;
}
```

csv

```
MRE1,MRE2,MRE3,MRE4,PolyPro,HygieneKit,PoopyWipes,Gloves,ExtraSocks1,ExtraSocks2,ExtraSocks3,Snacks,JetBoil,Ammo1,Ammo2,M16,SleepingBag,BivvySack,GoreTex,E-Tool,Canteens,FlakJacket,FrontSAPIPlate,BackSAPIPlate,WarBelt,Compass,NVG,Bayonet,Diary,Iodine,Knife,Lamp,Nameplate,Ointment,Quiver,Radio,Toothbrush,Utensils,Vitamins,X-acto Knife,Yellow safety belt,Zinc-oxide
2.125,2,1.875,2,1.5,2.5,0.5,0.5,0.25,0.25,0.25,1.5,1,3,3.75,7,5,2.5,2.5,3,4.25,3,8.25,8,3.5,1.125,1.125,5,0.75,0.375,0.875,1.125,0.25,0.875,3.75,7.625,0.375,0.25,0.125,3.75,2.125,4.625
12,10,8,6,10,5,6.5,4.5,9,6,2,1.5,5,15,100,80,35,22,18,12,18,30,50,25,12,50,3,86,50,6,9,5,1,8,7,20,5,2,1,5,2,6
```

The code I'm running only reads in the first first 3 items as a test, but only properly gets the first item name, the other 2 come out as weird characters.  How would I go about writing this to properly read the CSV and attach the appropriate weight and values to each item?

My Output

```
| MRE1 | | $5�� | | �¤ |
```

Comment: You need to read the comma after stopping at it: so `"%24[^,]"` should be `" %24[^,],"`. If you *always check* how many items were converted (the function return value) you can find these things. The extra space will deal with any newline in the stream. The 'weird characters' are from unuinitialised strings, that were not read into because the input has stalled at the unread comma.

Comment: @WeatherVane That works; you should post it as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: This is a FAQ. There are probably *thousands* of questions dealing with the `%[]` format.

Comment: Note that the last item in the row doesn't end with a comma but a newline. Off-the-cuff you could try this: `" %24[^,\n]%*c"` where the `%*c` reads and discards one unspecified character.

Comment: Would I use that in the same fscanf I'm using?  I tried that just now and it's not reading anything.

Comment: My small program containing `while(fscanf(fil, " %24[^,\n]%*c", str) == 1) printf("%s\n", str);` behaved as expected. You can then use `sscanf` or `strtod` to extract values from the non-name strings.

Comment: You might want to record the comma/newline so that you can tell a delineation between new rows.

Answer (score 1):

Consider reading the 3 lines using `fgets()` and then parse the lines.  Unless 3 lines read, no point in parsing.

Then parse the 3 lines, one at a time or as a group, as shown below.

This sample code uses `"%n"` to detect the offset of the scan, if it got that far.  Notice that the `','` is in the format.

Other code could use `strtod()`, `strcspn()`, `strtok()`, for parsing.

```
#define ITEM_N 100
#define NAME_SIZE 25

// Scale the max lines size in some fashion.
// I recommend 2x the maximum expected size.
#define LINE_SIZE ((ITEM_N * NAME_SIZE + 3)*2)

char lines[3][LINE_SIZE];
char *s[3];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (fgets(lines[i], sizeof lines[i], packingList) == NULL) {
    break;
  }
  s[i] = lines[i];
}

if (i == 3) {
  Item items[ITEM_N];
  size_t index;
  for (index = 0; index < ITEM_N; index++) {
    int n = 0;
    sscanf(s[0], "%24[^,]%*[,\n]%n", items[index].name, &n);
    if (n == 0) break;
    s[0] += n;

    n = 0;
    sscanf(s[1], "%lf%*[,\n]%n", &items[index].weight, &n);
    if (n == 0) break;
    s[1] += n;

    // likewise for .value (not shown)

  }
  
  // Code can now use `index` items.
}
```